# Cant enter value to object. Causing JSON Object response

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

I have a working php code that takes id and deviceID from JsonObjectRequest from my Android app. The problem is when is in "function authenticateUser". I cant seem to do this **operation $response->auth = "1";**.

When i comment this code, it doesn't produce any error and gives me the correct output except i get null for object auth. i can enter value for this two variables in object (**response->$isAuthenticated** and **response->$isSameUser**) but it produces error when i try to input for (**response->$auth**)

```
class Response{
    public $isAuthenticated;
    public $isSameUser;
    public $auth;
}

$response = new Response();
$error = array();
$log= array();

if(isset($decoded['id']) && isset($decoded['deviceID'])){
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    $id = $decoded['id'];
    $deviceID = $decoded['deviceID'];


    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        array_push($error,"Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $response -> isAuthenticated = checkIfAlreadyAuthenticated($conn, $id);
        if($response -> isAuthenticated ==0){
            array_push($log, $response -> isAuthenticated);
            authenticateUser($response, $conn, $id, $deviceID);

        }
        elseif($response -> isAuthenticated ==1){
            array_push($log, $response -> isAuthenticated);
            $response -> isSameUser = checkIfSameUser($conn, $id, $deviceID);
        }

    }

}
else{
    //echo 'POST ERROR';
}

function checkIfSameUser($conn, $id, $deviceID){
    $sql = "SELECT pin, deviceID FROM nextrack_userauthentication";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id_fromDB = $row["pin"]; 
            $deviceID_fromDB = $row["deviceID"];
        }
    } else {
        //echo "checkifSameUser Method SQL ERROR";
    }

    if((($id_fromDB == $id) == TRUE) AND (($deviceID_fromDB == $deviceID)== TRUE)){
        return 1;
    }

}

function authenticateUser($conn, $id, $deviceID){
    $authenticate = "1";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO nextrack_userauthentication(pin, activated, deviceID) VALUES ('".$id."','".$authenticate."','".$deviceID."')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0)
    {
        $response->auth = "1";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $response->auth = "0";
    }

}

function checkIfAlreadyAuthenticated($conn, $id){
    $sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT'". $id ."' FROM nextrack_userauthentication WHERE pin='" . $id ."'";

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT '". $id ."' FROM nextrack_userauthentication WHERE pin='" . $id ."'");

    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off to get `authenticateUser()` to just return 1 or 0, depending on the success of the login and assign this in the calling part.  This means that `authenticateUser()` isn't directly linked to a response, but just a case of is the operation OK or not...

```
   function authenticateUser($conn, $id, $deviceID){
        $authenticate = "1";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO nextrack_userauthentication(pin, activated, deviceID) VALUES ('".$id."','".$authenticate."','".$deviceID."')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0)
        {
            return "1";
        } 
        else 
        {
            return "0";
        }

    }
```

And then...

```
    if($response -> isAuthenticated ==0){
        $response->auth = authenticateUser($conn, $id, $deviceID);
    }
```

You could also use `auth` as true or false and then your function becomes...

```
   function authenticateUser($conn, $id, $deviceID){
        $authenticate = "1";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO nextrack_userauthentication(pin, activated, deviceID) VALUES ('".$id."','".$authenticate."','".$deviceID."')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        return (mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0);
    }
```

Comment: I did exactly the same thing. But it still produces the same error. But i can access the other 2 variables in from my object except for $response -> auth

Comment: In your original code, both other accesses are outside a function, so they are in the global scope, which is where `$response` is defined.  As soon as you call a function, this is when a new scope comes into play.

Comment: Can you check the updated answer which shows where to place the use of `$response->auth` and see if that is OK?

Comment: Thanks. I just corrected it. Just one question, do "if-else" have scope like functions too?

Comment: If..else.. and loops don't introduce their own scopes, so if you define something inside an if block of code, it exists after the if is completed.